Error 0xC0000005 when importing a module generated with Boost::Python
I have the following benchmark.cpp file:
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
    return "hello, world";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(benchmark)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("greet", greet);
}

which is built using CMakeLists.txt containing i.a. the following pieces of code:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

find_package (Python3 COMPONENTS Interpreter Development REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS python REQUIRED)

set(BENCHMARK_MODULE benchmark)
add_library(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} MODULE benchmark.cpp)
set_target_properties(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} PROPERTIES PREFIX "" SUFFIX ".pyd")
target_include_directories(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
target_include_directories(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_include_directories(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} SYSTEM PUBLIC ${Python3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} PUBLIC ${Python3_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(${BENCHMARK_MODULE} PUBLIC ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

I'm building on Windows 10 using MSYS2's MinGW64 and Ninja generator; using Python 3.12.
Dependencies - An open-source modern Dependency Walker gave me the following dependencies for benchmark.pyd:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVCRT.dll
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libstdc++-6.dll
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\libboost_python311-mt.dll
C:\Program Files\Python312\python312.dll

so in Python code, I've tried to import that module in the following way:
import os
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin')
[os.add_dll_directory(path) for path in sys.path if os.path.isdir(path)]

import benchmark

but when I run this code, I get "Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)" message when importing benchmark module.
What is the reason for such behavior? How to fix it?

If dependencies can find these libraries, so can your program. 0xC0000005 is a memory violation. Run your code under a debugger to see where it crashes. My money is on a mismatch between compilers, since you have BOTH MSVCRT.dll and libstdc++.

@Botje: When I try to debug "import benchmark" statement, I can only enter _Finder.find_spec() function from _virtualenv.py module (I try to run my script using a VirtualEnv) - for other levels I get "" status in PyCharm or simply nothing in Visual Studio Code.
Could you elaborate on that compiler mismatch? I thought MSVCRT.dll and kernel32.dll were added because the shared library was built on Windows - and that they are sort of compiler-agnostic... PS 0xC0000005 is a general "Access Violation" error, not necessarily related to memory violation.

Make sure you are debugging the native side, since that's where the crash is.
